# Undirected graph, check if path exists between nodes

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to check if there is path from one vertex to any from several other vertices *(in my particular case, i need to check if there is way from top of the wall to the any other brick that is on the ground, and every brick is a vertex)*.

I have found some algorithms, but i need simplified version just to check if the path exists. (it'd be good if i also could have number of the possible paths. )

I'm new to the graphs and searched a lot about these search algorithms before asking here, but i couldn't figure out how to implement them in my situation.

Edit 1: I forgot to add that i can have hundreds of bricks (vertices) and need fastest way of checking if path exists. I have searched Dijkstra's algorithm and it looks too complicated. And for some reason there are more tutorials and explanations for Directed graphs, so that's the reason why i am writing question here.

for now i have vertex class:

```
public class Vertex : MonoBehaviour {

public string id;

public float x; // Horizontal coord
public float y; // Vertical coord

public Vertex(string id, float x, float y)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
}
```

and edge class:

```
public class Edge : MonoBehaviour {

public Vertex Vertex1; // Vertex one
public Vertex Vertex2; // Vertex two

public Edge(Vertex Vertex1, Vertex Vertex2)
{
    this.Vertex1 = Vertex1;
    this.Vertex2 = Vertex2;
}
}
```

**Dont really know how to represent them in graph**, because as input i have 3 dimensional wall and after some bricks are destroyed i need to check if top brick has path to any of the bottom bricks that are on floor, because if not wall will basically collapse. So looks like I have to check in 3 dimensions for all paths.

Edit 2:

in vertex class i added neighbors list `public List<Vertex> Neighbours;`
   but still can't figure out how to represent graph in 3d so at least you could tell me how it'd be represented in 2d.

ps(thank you all for comments and answers I really appreciate them).

Comment: Use Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: In what form do you store your graph?  Adjacency matrix or something else? Provide some code pls.

Comment: Search how to represent a graph, then an algorithm for path finding (or do one by you) and if yet you have problems post your code so community can help you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: @jdweng [Dijsktra's Algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/) is for finding the shortest path between source and other vertices. While connectivity between two vertices can be checked through [Breadth First Search](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/)
 and [Depth First Search](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/). Though Djisktra could work in this case but time complexity is improved in case of BFS and DFS.

Comment: Because I missed lot of information to add, I made update to my question.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is to make sure you don't get into loops when going through a graph.  The most common method to use with graph is shortest path, but it is not the only reason for using Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @jdweng I don't get it not getting into loops can be ensured even in BFS and DFS. And the OP nowhere talks about shortest path.

Comment: BFS and DFS are trees.  So trees don't normally have loops.  The request here is undirected graph and not tree.

Comment: @jdweng they can be applied to general graphs, just without the optimization that leaves out the "visited" set

Comment: Aren't trees just general graphs without loops?   Lets not get people too confused.  When you have loops you must include the visited set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find any path, you can use depth-first search. To find a shortest path, you can use breadth-first search. To find all paths (hence the number of paths), you can use either of the above and modify to (a) continue after finding the target node and (b) see if other paths can reach the target node (though it may have been reached previously). To find the path of least weight to the node (in a weighted graph), you can use Dijkstra's algorithm (no negative edges), Bellman-Ford (negative edges OK) or Floyd-Warshall (no negative cycles).

Comment: How would be graph represented in the DFS? do i even need edge class? or i can just use vertexes.

Comment: @Nick You can represent the graph as an adjacency list, adjacency matrix or as a sort of graph structure directly. What you need for DFS and BFS is a way to tell which vertices have already been visited, which must be stored in additional memory no matter how you slice it.

Comment: ok i represent graph using adjacency list, but can't figure out the way to auto generate it. for now edges array looks like this: _var edges = new[]{Tuple.Create(1,2), Tuple.Create(2,4), Tuple.Create(4,3), Tuple.Create(4,1), Tuple.Create(3,2), Tuple.Create(3,1) };_ so what is the way of doing it using loop? for eg: I have 1000 vertexes and its rectangular wall so there should be a way for it right? btw your answer really helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

With a bit of pre-processing, you can answer those queries in near-constant time, which is useful when you have to test several pairs of nodes (it seems like you do).

The pre-processing is simple: initialize a disjoint set with V items (V is the number of vertices), then for every edge (x,y) call `union(x, y)`. This is almost linear in the number of edges ("almost" meaning it differs by an inverse Ackerman factor, which is so close to constant that it might as well be actually constant).

To find whether there is a path between `x` and `y`, test `find(x) == find(y)`.

You could find the number of possible paths between any pair by raising the adjacency matrix to the V'th power (using any fast exponentiation algorithm, but it will still be relatively slow).

Comment: Very elegant. I think this beats hands down the graph approach. However, this requires a clever implementation of disjoint sets. Maybe you happen to know a good C# one to recommend to the OP?

Comment: @Rerito I don't know one, but it's quite easy to write. For example for the basics, here's [this older answer from me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798351/555045)

Answer (score 2):

It is simple

1. Put source vertex into queue
2. check if queue is empty, you are done, no path if not
3. check if it is one of the vertexes from the destination set, if yes you are done, path exists, if not, put all neighbors of that vertex to queue repeat steep 2

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide some extra "pseudo code" ('d be glad if you actually used c# but still) because it's hard for me to implement it.

Comment: @Nick, that is called BSF, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32212/Introduction-to-Graph-with-Breadth-First-Search-BF

Comment: Thanks, unfortuantely I can't accept all answers, but i can upwote it :)

Answer (score 1):

You only want to test for a path existence, so your best bet from a graph theory perspective is to use a BFS.

You have a source vertex *src* and a set *S<sub>tgt</sub>* of target vertices.

Since your graph is undirected when the BFS is over you will have the set of vertices of the connected component containing *src*. Just check if *S<sub>tgt</sub>* is a subset of that set.

To sum up:

1. Let *S<sub>bfs</sub>* be an empty hashset of vertices
2. Perform a BFS starting from *src*:

   1. When you discover a vertex *v*, insert it into *S<sub>bfs</sub>*
3. Perform the intersection of *S<sub>bfs</sub>* and *S<sub>tgt</sub>* to get all the target vertices that are reachable from *src*

Answer (score 0):

Since you are seeking a simple solution, I would use a breadth-first search.  A less-simple solution would involve something like the All-Pairs shortest path algorithm to determine the shortest path between every pair of nodes in a graph.